# Can't install dash/plotly and several others (is it proxy problem?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, plotly-dash

I am using my company laptop to install dash & plotly. While this works fine on my personal laptop, I am wondering if these errors are due to security (when I try installing on my company laptop)?

*Typing it out manually because I work in a bank and don't have the guts to risk it.

```
Warning: Retrying (Retry(total = 4, connect=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError' ('cannot connect to proxy.'), OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))':/simple/dash/
Warning: Retrying (Retry(total = 3, connect=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError' ('cannot connect to proxy.'), OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))':/simple/dash/
Warning: Retrying (Retry(total = 2, connect=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError' ('cannot connect to proxy.'), OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))':/simple/dash/
Warning: Retrying (Retry(total = 1, connect=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError' ('cannot connect to proxy.'), OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))':/simple/dash/
Warning: Retrying (Retry(total = 0, connect=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError' ('cannot connect to proxy.'), OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))':/simple/dash/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dash (from versions:none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dash
```

---

I just want to know, is this a problem that can be fixed if I were to go to the office and hook my laptop to the ethernet, or is this a security problem?
Is there any way to go around it without committing a federal crime?

Comment: error shows `cannot connect to proxy` so it seems problem with internet. Can you connect with any web pages on this computer? If this is company laptop then it may be configured to access internet only using company network and this connection may have problem. If you can connect to pypi.com then you can download module from this page and later install it from local disk. It doesn't committing federal crime but if this is company laptop then it can commit "company crime"

Comment: Hello, what is pypi.com? I can't seem to access it even on my personal laptop. And yes, this computer is able to connect to my home internet via VPN (on days when I work from home). I have managed to pip install pandas, matplotlib and scikit-learn. Hence not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Hello, alright I managed to access pypi.org however am unable to download (blocked by company's security). Do you have any other alternatives?

Comment: if you access web page then it should also download - it should tread it as another page to display. But you can download on other computer and copy with USB pendrive. For small module you could even send by email.

Comment: Hi unfortunately, I work in a big bank with access to highly sensitive data. Downloading from the web page is blocked by security and the use of USB thumbdrive will basically get me fired immediately (I think we have a system where the IT department gets notified the moment someone inserts a thumb drive in). I am not sure of the email method, but I did try yesterday and could not attach some of the docs in the packages (blocked by gmail). Either ways it seems like a risky endeavor. I think I will try downloading again when I get to the office and hook it to the ethernet.